# Ionic 3 file access storage android 11 issue. Play store rejecting the application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-11

I have developed an application in IONIC 3 and I am accessing file manager to store the file and read files. For android 11 I have added
"MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Play store is rejecting my application , since for accessing file manager and creating SQLite database in internal storage I need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
[image]

This is how I am creating SQLite database.

import { SQLiteObject, SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

```
this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'test.db',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    this.dbsql = db;
     this.CreateTables();
  }).catch(e => this.appmanager.ConsoleLog("DataB  new", e));
```

This is how I am creating folder in file manager.

```
this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory,AppConstants.IMG_FOLDER, false).then((entry) => {}).catch((err) => {
```

})

[image]

Comment: The email is pretty clear tbh, there are other alternatives to use storage like MediaStore, and I don't know how your database gets involved in this permission.

Comment: @javdromero is MediaStore and contentResolver availble in ionic. After removing MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission database is not creating